Building Node/Vite app with Heroku - fails on build step because it can't find the correct vite.config.js file
Apologies in advance if this is a noob question, I'm relatively new to the production and hosting side of web dev. I'm hosting a Node app using Vite on Heroku, and when I try to do a manual deploy from my git repo, the build always fails.
The heroku buildpack is successfully installing all node dependencies and then failing when trying to run 'vite build'.
Here is the error message from the Heroku build log:
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > vite-project@0.0.0 build
       > vite build --config vite.config.js
       
failed to load config from /tmp/build_19c166a1/vite.config.js
error during build:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_19c166a1undefined'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:580:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/vite.config.js.timestamp-1722453721387-d069f9340d625.mjs:11:14
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:66979:15)
    at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:66820:24)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:66430:24)
    at async build (file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:65525:18)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///tmp/build_19c166a1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:828:5)
-----> Build failed

Part of the error message seems to indicate it can find the vite config just fine, but the other part is showing that it receives 'undefined' instead of '/vite.config.js'.
I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot because I don't truly understand what the heroku nodejs buildpack is doing under the hood or how to look into that. Any help is greatly appreciated.
PS: I ran a fresh Vite demo app on Heroku and the build step worked just fine, so it doesn't seem to be a Vite issue specifically.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "21.x"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run serve\" \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run frontend\"",
    "serve": "nodemon src/backend/server.js",
    "frontend": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --config vite.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.12.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "idb": "^8.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-button": "^0.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "sass": "^1.76.0",
    "soundfont-player": "^0.12.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "vite-plugin-sass": "^0.1.0"
  }
}


Getting the same error for a Rails API and React front-end using Vite on Heroku. Even posted my own question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79035572/deploy-rails-7-api-with-react-front-end-using-vite-to-heroku, Did you ever find a solution?
