Deploy Rails 7 API with React front-end using Vite to Heroku
I've built a basic Rails 7 API with React front-end using Vite. The project was also created with:
npm create vite@latest

command if its helpful for context. The issue I'm facing is that the app runs fine locally but components/routes won't render on Heroku.
The app uses React Router to handle routing so I understand that this will cause an issue with routes being shown as expected via Heroku due to the content being rendered client-side. I've been attempting to solve this using the Nginx buildpack for Heorku.
However, I've been struggling to get my components to display successfully after deploying - despite configuring NodeJS, Ruby, and Nginx buildpack (in that order) and following numerous rabbit holes from similar posts here:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx

How to deploy React front end + Rails api backend with nginx, capistrano and passenger

https://medium.com/@murithibrianm/solving-react-routing-on-production-nginx-configuration-eb98c7ab34a7

https://gist.github.com/huangzhuolin/24f73163e3670b1cd327f2b357fd456a


Here are some screenshots and files for reference:
File Structure
Again, this app was setup using the Vite command above so this structure is what is provided out of the box.

It seems like Heroku may be looking for my vite.config.js file in the /app/frontend/ directory instead of the /frontend/ directory based on the Heroku logs:

Package.json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.1.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.1",
    "@mui/material": "^6.1.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^6.1.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.18.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.18.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.13",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}


nginx.conf.erb
daemon off;
# Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_proxied any; # Heroku router sends Via header

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    # Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            # Uncomment this if statement to force SSL/redirect http -> https
            # if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
            #   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            # }

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}

vite.json
{
  "all": {
    "sourceCodeDir": "frontend",
    "watchAdditionalPaths": []
  },
  "development": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-dev",
    "port": 3036
  },
  "test": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-test",
    "port": 3037
  }
}


vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://fake.herokuapp.com/', // Uncomment this line while deploying to Heroku
        // target: 'http://localhost:3000', // Uncommnet this line while developing locally - Replace with your Rails API URL
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
})


Any insight here would be greatly appreciated!

Please don't use screenshots of the logs, code or any other text. They are not searchable or copyable. The only time screenshots are useful is to show what something rendered looks like.

Thanks. Will keep this in mind.
